# M.2 SSD not working on HP Elitebook x360 830 G6

Tags: ssd, m.2, hp-elitebook, hp-laptop

Today I removed an M.2 SSD from another PC and tried to install it on my HP Laptop. Thing is, when I boot to Windows, the SSD is not recognized. Not even on Diskpart. I also tried to modify anything on the BIOS, thought the port could have been software disabled or something, but I couldn't find anything.

The slot is originally made to plug the antenna on some models, but this is not the case and the slot comes free. Maybe it is not compatible with the SSD?

I'll leave some images just in case.

[image: HP Elitebook x360 830 G6]

[image: SSD]

[image: M.2 Slot]

Comment: This is likely to do with M.2 SATA vs M.2 PCIe.  I'm not an expert here by any stretch, but have you checked if there is a BIOS upgrade you can do?

Answer (score 1):

According to the specs, [HP EliteBook x360 830 G6 Notebook PC Specifications](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06355681) - [Storage/drives](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06355681#AbT6), both M.2 SATA and NVMe are supported:

[image: Screenshot of supported drives]

Your drive is a Toshiba 1.6 M.2 Internal SSD PCIe NVMe 128GB Solid State Drive ***SSS0P38304***, which should be compatible... so it isn't clear why it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting SSD you have there. Yeah unless the motherboard says it's an m.2 slot I wouldn't put it in there. Most laptops wouldn't have one unless it's really fancy. It looks like another slot for network adapters and other hardware like you said.

Also make sure you are only planning on setting not as a secondary drive for storage or else you will have problems.

Hope I helped.

Comment: No, this isn't an answer and is completely wrong. The OP has a M.2 slot. However, this isn't enough. Answer is actually in this comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1660876/m-2-ssd-not-working-on-hp-elitebook-x360-830-g6/1660905#comment2544607_1660876

Comment: @ChanganAuto Okay, I was just trying to help. The author should've closed this question if the answer was in the comment. I don't know why you would care about this post anymore as I answered over a year ago.

Comment: Why would a suggestion in a comment cause the OP to close the question? Only an answer can be accepted, not a comment - and even then, then question isn't "closed", just marked as answered... Nevertheless, @ChanganAuto the specs state that the M.2 slot can accept *both* SATA ad NVMe, so the comment *may* not be totally accurate - see my answer.

Comment: @Greenonline I see